# Dissolve field while preserving another related field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I am using 'Store' as dissolve field and 'Profit' as statistics field with statistic type 'MAX', and would like to preserve the related 'Fruit'.

This is my original table:

```
____________________________
| Store |  Fruit  | Profit |
|   A   |  Orange |   20   |
|   A   |  Apple  |   30   |
|   B   |  Banana |   15   |
|   B   |  Grape  |   10   |
|   C   |  Apple  |   35   |
```

This is what I want:

```
________________________________
| Store |  Fruit  | MAX_Profit |
|   A   |  Apple  |     30     |
|   B   |  Banana |     15     |
|   C   |  Apple  |     35     |
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Summary Statistics tool?

Comment: Sort by profit, delete duplicates by store.